# Create new content missing when adding a component in experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I'm using `Sitecore 9.3 with JSS 13`.

When I try to use the `add here` and select one of my components I get the `Select the associated Content` dialog box. This box is missing the `create new content` option.

https://gyazo.com/460e540ff5a3de341d20603d496a70b3

How can I get the create a new content option?

Comment: did you select on your rendering the data source template?

Comment: That is default set when you use jss deploy app -c -d

Comment: Reinstall sitecore without SXA fixed the problem